# Rotating log files on HDFS

Tags: logging, rotation, hdfs

From a bash script that is executed on a spark cluster, we log to dated files (processing.2018-07-25.log).

```
LOGFILE="processing.2018-07-25.log"
....
echo 'Log line' | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
....
hdfs dfs -put -f $LOGFILE /user/myuser/logs
```

Now we'd like to delete log files older than x days, ia make logs rotating.

Is there any built-in function or lib (bash/hadoop/spark) compatible with HDFS, or should this be done manually?

Thx.

Comment: Nothing should be done manually, surely? We have some scripting stuff that we need to do at times that does not work under hdfs. We got names and pumped them over to local file system where scripts worked and we then used those results against HDFS.

Comment: Can you explain your solution please?

Comment: Well, I am not on that LINUX box now, but I remember we found that certain ls and dir commands did not work, so we got a list and touched the filenames to the local file system and ran the scripts there and then processed the results based on these back in HDFS. I sense that may be this is what you are facing. I will check tomorrow.